# Want to use VTD-XML to extract inner Xml: Guess this is what VTDNav.getContentFragment is for. How does is work?

Tags: xml, parsing

I am trying to figure out how I could extract an inner Xml String from a Xml document. 
According to the API there a method VTDNav.getContentFragment() which seems to be the right choice. But this method returns a long. How do I use that long value to retrieve the xml between the two tags?
Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

VTDNav.getContentFragment returns a long, the upper 32 bits is the length of the fragment, lower 32 bit is the offset, to retrieve the document text between tags, see the example below

...

```
VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
long l = vn.getContentFragment();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("out.txt");
fos.write(vn.getXML().getBytes(), (int)l, (int)(l<<32));
```

Comment: @John - to be fair, this is actually a VTD-XML question; not sure you can count that one...

Comment: @marc: I'd still like disclosure. I'd even waive the "No tag-lines or signatures rule", to make it convenient for him.